# What kind of Database use as local database for PC Software?

Tags: java, mysql, database, oracle, sqlite

I want to build simple a Windows PC Software with Java. I need to store some extra data like 100 phone contacts. I can do with Oracle or MySQL database or Array in code. But the problem is this DBMS need server offline or online and I don't want to put data direct on code.If I use from my localhost When I will give it to my friends the can't access it. I also don't want to i use online database. I just want local database or resource system like android values resource or sqlite. How can I do it? Any ideas are welcomed.

Comment: personal preference.

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by personal preference. @Fallenreaper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is called an [embedded database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database).

There are several Java embedded databases, for example [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html), [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/), [Apache Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/). [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) can also be used in regular Java applications, it's not Android-specific.

Answer (score 0):

I use Apache Derby for  all of my embedded database. You can also use Sun's Java DB that is based on Derby but the latest version of Derby is much newer. It supports a lot of options that commercial, native databases support but is much smaller and easier to embed.

Answer (score 0):

I have looked some time ago and haven't found an embedded database that could be used for storing a "handful" of data...the smallest if i am not mistaken is H2 but still is 1M+
There have being some projects that covers these needs but they seem to be "abandon ware" like this: http://www.smallsql.de
I guess the best solution is to use an Xml file for read/write.